# database - retrieve results for unused positions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, database-design

How do I retrieve results for not used positions in my database. Here is an example:

```
TABLE POSITION
PosID    PosName
101      President
102      Vice President
103      Secretary
104      Treasurer
105      Auditor
106      Srgt of Arms

TABLE OFFICER
OfficerID     OrganizationID   Name   PosID (FK to TABLE POSITION)
1001          2016-02081-0    Kris    101
1002          2016-02081-0    Nitche  102
1003          2016-02081-0    Russel  103
```

Now I want my query to retrieve positions from the TABLE POSITION where the position is not being used by a certain organization. This is what i did which returns too many results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM POSITION, OFFICER 
WHERE OrganizationID = '2016-02081-0' AND OFFICER.PosID != POSITION.PosID;
```

Take note that I want to retrieve only the following result

```
TABLE POSITION
PosID    PosName
104      Treasurer
105      Auditor
106      Srgt of Arms
```

It should retrieve positions not being used by the organizationID of '2016-02081-0'

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer to indicate that it helped you, by cllicking the check mark icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM POSITION 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM OFFICER 
                  WHERE OrganizationID = '2016-02081-0' AND 
                        OFFICER.PosID = POSITION.PosID);
```

The above query returns all `POSITION` records not being related to an `OFFICER` record having `OrganizationID = '2016-02081-0'`.

Comment: wooaaah @.@ thanks...i appreciate it my good sir! :) makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `not in` operator:

```
SELECT PosID
FROM   position
WHERE  PosID NOT IN (SELECT PosID 
                     FROM   officer)
```

Or the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT PosID
FROM   position p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   officer o
                   WHERE  p.PosId = o.PosId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a left join to do this. This way we do not need a sub query.

```
  SELECT     p.*
  FROM       Position p
  LEFT JOIN  Officer o on o.PosID = p.PosID and OrganizationID = '2016-02081-0'
  WHERE      o.OfficerId is null
```